# SSH client option to suppress server banners?

Tags: ssh, banner

I've read [Stop ssh login from printing motd from the client?](https://serverfault.com/questions/36421/stop-ssh-login-from-printing-motd-from-the-client), however my situation is a bit different :

- I want to keep Banner /path/to/sometxt serverside
- I would like to pass an option under specific conditions so that Banner is not printed (eg `ssh -o "PrintBanner=No" someserver`).

Any idea?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**You can't.** (At least not with stock OpenSSH)

The server banner is sent by the server before authentication happens. It's point is usually to contain a legal disclaimer or similar "If you're not authorized disconnect NOW" type message, or other critical things you don't want the remote user to be able to suppress/ignore.

If you really want to get rid of this you will need to hack and compile your own customized version of the SSH client.

Comment: This is old information and no longer true on common distributions.  The answers below to use either `-q` or `-o LogLevel=error` work great now :-)

Comment: "You can't. (At least not with stock OpenSSH) The server banner is sent by the server before authentication happens." ... Are you **ACTUALLY** FOR REAL ?!? imagine that banner contains private information in that company, no one would use ssh anymore if such **HORRIBLE BREACH OF SECURTY** would be in place ! ... TURN THE POWER ON DUDE !

Answer (score 79):

There is a `LogLevel` option:

It silences the banner but you're still able to receive errors:

```
$ ssh -o LogLevel=error localhost 
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: Didn't work with OpenSSH 6.9 client - perhaps version information would be useful?

Comment: Works with OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Answer (score 16):

I 've tested it, I think u can use `-q` in the ssh command. Parameter -q was means *Quiet mode*. It causes most warning and diagnostic messages to be suppressed, e.g.

```
ssh -t '$node2' 'sudo cat xxx' |grep xxxxx" 2>/dev/null >/root/node2
```

or

```
ssh -t -q '$node2' 'sudo cat xxxx' |grep xxx" >/root/node2
```

Hope this can help others

Comment: -q didn't work from a Fedora 22 client to Centos 6 and Suse 2.6 (client was OpenSSH 6.9.

Maybe this answer would be upvoted if it referenced specific ssh version?

Answer (score 13):

Update ~/.ssh/config with following to suppress banner

```
Host *
    LogLevel error
```

Comment: I believe the "Host *" line is either redundant or incorrect. At any rate, I get the desired effect without it. Altho it should be noted that OP wanted to get the effect under certain programmatic conditions, in which case the command line option listed above is the better solution.

Answer (score 9):

Seems like you're looking for **-q**:

***Quiet mode.  Causes most warning and diagnostic messages to be suppressed.***

```
ssh user@host
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
| banner: blah                                                                 |
*------------------------------------------------------------------------------*
Last login: Mon Oct  2 16:40:01 2017 from ipAddress
$
```

With `-q`

```
ssh -q user@host
Last login: Mon Oct  2 16:40:30 2017 from ipAddress
$
```

Nice and quiet. The banner is still configured but you're not bothered by it.

On another note: don't use banners. It's best not to confirm or deny anything. It won't help you with the people you weren't worried about and the people you are worried about will laugh as they work past it `;-)`

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to set a different `Banner` (to none) inside a `Match` block.

For instance:

```
Match Address 192.0.2.0/24
        Banner none
```

But this has to be done *server-side*, based on specific conditions. You can't do it from the *client* side.

Answer (score 4):

For me, `-o LogLevel=error` was better than `-q`, because the latter suppresses the important error information (which you can then obtain only via exit code).

Compare this (without options):

`[root@myserver804 myuser1]# ssh targetserver1; echo "exit code=$?"
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:hvtR8Dl09aUeCeG2cT5EA8b+nbCOoV6h1DUON2vE63w.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1735
RSA host key for targetserver1 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
exit code=255`

with this (quiet)

`[root@myserver804 myuser1]# ssh -q targetserver1; echo "exit code=$?"
exit code=255`

with this (only log errors)

`[root@myserver804 myuser1]# ssh -o LogLevel=error targetserver1; echo "exit code=$?"
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
SHA256:hvtR8Dl09aUeCeG2cT5EA8b+nbCOoV6h1DUON2vE63w.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending RSA key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1735
RSA host key for targetserver1 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
exit code=255`

So the conclusion is - if you are still interested in relevant errors, use `-o LogLevel=error`

Comment: "-q" is definetly not a good option indeed :)

Comment: On centos 7.9 the output of "-q" and "-o ..." is exactly the same.
Meaning that they both show the output that you posted.

Answer (score 2):

Neither the `-q` or the `-oLogLevel=error` works.

What does work is to suppress **STDERR**

`ssh hostname command 2>/dev/null`

The downside, however, is that the **STDERR** suppression is applied to the entire command and not just the SSH program.

Answer (score 2):

On a user basis you can suppress server banners by creating an empty file in a user's $HOME directory (/home/username/) called .hushlogin.

```
touch ~/.hushlogin
```

Comment: does not work for banner served prior to login.

Answer (score 2):

Ok adding my resolution.
I discovered that I was getting different results depending on how I used ssh.

```
ssh -q tgt true
No Banner

ssh -q tgt <<EOF
true
EOF
Banner

ssh -q tgt bash <<EOF
true
EOF
No Banner
```

Comment: Nice! bash call solved it for me.

Comment: Best. I solved my issue by this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ssh -q
```

my ssh conections, do not get a banner message.

Answer (score -2):

Just call a shell, that should suppress the banner.

```
ssh you@someplace.com /bin/bash
```

Note though, for me at least, my $PS1 doesn't get set, so it looks like it's hanging. I had to type a couple of commands to verify that it was working.

Comment: This won't suppress banners shown by the `Banner` option in `/etc/sshd_config` (at least it doesn't on FreeBSD / OpenSSH_5.8p2)

Comment: Ah, I saw motd in the question.  That'll learn me to read the description properly ;)

Answer (score -3):

For me -q did the trick and I was still able to work with the output saved to a file.

ssh -q root@server28 "ls -alF /dr_mksysb |egrep -v \"total|lost+found|./|../\" |awk '{print \$NF}' |sed 's/.\$//g'" > ${basedir}/28.list

Comment: Great that it works for you. Nevertheless this doesn't answer the question and should be a comment at most.

Comment: That's the problem, it does answer the question, I got rid of motd (banner) I had exactly the same problem as stated in the question

Comment: The only part of your answer that relates to the question is the `-q` parameter. The rest is completely unrelated and is only helpful to you. The parameter has already been given as an answer, so feel free to upvote it if it helped you, but this "answer" will only receive downvotes