# Ignore PSA when running command over SSH and expecting a response

Tags: ssh

When I send a command to a server e.g.

```
ssh myuser@fooserver.org <<EOS
# run a command that returns an output
EOS
```

What can I do to suppress the initial feedback e.g.

```
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-66-generic x86_64)
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/36421/stop-ssh-login-from-printing-motd-from-the-client#38160

Comment: Do you really need to provide the remote command in a heredoc instead of just on the command line?

Comment: I wanted it to be easy to read as a heredoc format but if there's no way way of doing it then I could condense to a single line